# How to transpose a spark dataset in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I new to spark java i wanted to transpose dataset. I have checked the pivot function to transpose the the dataset but the header are unknown to me so cannot use the pivot fuction to do so is there any way in java i can transpose the dataset .

Comment: in which format are you collecting the data??

Comment: i collecting the data in spark Dataset<Row> format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will transpose the dataset in spark using a pivot column.

```
private static Dataset<Row> transposeDF(Dataset<Row> df, String[] columns, String pivotCol) {
    List<String> columnsValue =
        Arrays.asList(columns).stream().map(x -> "'" + x + "', " + x).collect(Collectors.toList());

    String stackCols = String.join(",", columnsValue);
    Dataset<Row> df1 =
        df.selectExpr(pivotCol, "stack(" + columns.length + "," + stackCols + ")")
            .select(pivotCol, "col0", "col1");

    Dataset<Row> finalDF =
        df1.groupBy(functions.col("col0"))
            .pivot(pivotCol)
            .agg(functions.concat_ws("", functions.collect_list(functions.col("col1"))))
            .withColumnRenamed("col0", pivotCol);
    return finalDF;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that SparkSQL doesn't have a transpose function. So you must create a new Schema for your dataset as well as create a mapper function in order to change the location of rows to columns.

Comment: can you share some example for your approach

Comment: yes, for sure. let me some moment